# My image div taking up the entire top section of the browser, how do I fix this?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My image div seems to be taking up the entire top section of the browser, I am not sure what I did wrong, but in order to make the text align within the image, I will have to add top:250px, that doesn't seem right to me. Here is my code:         http://jsfiddle.net/Swathi56/zzbwkoLj/1/

I have attached the image for your reference. [image]

```
<div>
      <div class="hero-image-download col-xs-12">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <div class="hero-text-download text-center">
              <h1>aspenONE Download Center</h1>
              <h2> Download your UPGRADE now!</h2>
              <p>Simply select software suite and you need to start using the latest version. 
              It’s fast and easy</p>
            </div>
        </div>
     <div class="engineering-section">
          <div class="engineering-section-title title-text">Engineering</div>
    </div>
</div><!--end div-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `top: 250px;` from your text and set their parent DIV's (`.hero-text-download`) position to absolute and align it to the bottom of it's parent DIV (`bottom: 0;`).

```
   .hero-image-download .hero-text-download {
        position:absolute;
        margin:auto;
        bottom: 0;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zzbwkoLj/2/

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
   background-size:cover 
   height:500px
```

from the .hero-image-download class styling.

After this you do not need to add `top:250px` in the text containers.

I hope this will help

Comment: My problem is that the <div class="hero-image-download col-xs-12"> takes up the entire top section in the web browser, It should only take the div class="hero-image-download" section, not the header section as well. I hope I am making sense.

Comment: removing the height makes the whole image disappeared.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with the actual elements of your page like header section and image

Comment: Hi Ankit, this is my fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/Swathi56/zzbwkoLj/3/   the images are not showing up since I have them local on my desktop. Thanks!